# mod_evasive module DOSSystemCommand and DOSEmailNotify option are not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache2, apache-modules, mod-evasive

I have installed apache2 with mod_evasive module on Ubuntu 10.04 and I would like to get an email alert whenever mod_evasive blacklist an IP. For that I have mentioned my email address in /etc/apache2/conf.d/modevasive. when I send an email from terminal /bin/echo 'test apache mod' | sudo /bin/mail -s 'test apache mod' vinish@example.com I will receive and email

Even If I mention it under with DOSSystemCommand it won't work for me

If trying block website using perl script and I have mentioned log file also /etc/apache2/conf.d/modevasive file and its works file so that means modules is working somehow DOSSystemCommand and DOSEmailNotify option are not working

Answer (score 0):

Straight from [Linode Library](http://library.linode.com/web-servers/apache/mod-evasive)

> Be sure MAILER is set correctly in mod_evasive.c (or mod_evasive20.c).
>   The default is "/bin/mail -t %s" where %s is used to denote the
>   destination email address set in the configuration. If you are running
>   on linux or some other operating system with a different type of
>   mailer, you'll need to change this.